# What are the legal obligations of non-profit organizations as distinct from for-profit?

Tags: united-states, business, non-profit

For-profit businesses have many obligations such as paying taxes, keeping records, fair hiring practices, proper classification of employees, etc.

Many of these obligations are shared by non-profit organizations.

Many for-profit obligations are not required for non-profit organizations, such as paying taxes.

But what obligations, if any, do non-profit organizations have that for-profit organizations do not have?

[image]

Comment: Do you mean, more specifically, what are the roles and responsibilities of the board of directors?

Comment: Yes, many nonprofits have boards of directors. Nonprofits are not all that different from corporations in many cases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Canada, there is a *restriction* for not-for-profit organizations: "no part of its income may be paid or made available for the personal benefit of any proprietor, member, or shareholder (with an exception for amateur athletic organizations)." Source: https://www.cof.org/content/nonprofit-law-canada.